# Distributing 4 distinct balls into 3 distinct bins($bin_1,bin_2,bin_3$) , such that $bin_2$ always has a ball

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification

> Distributing 4 distinct balls into 3 distinct
> bins($bin_1,bin_2,bin_3$) , such that $bin_2$ always has a ball

My approach to this problem is that without any conditions the total way of distributing the balls is $3^4 = 81$.

Now we deduct all the ways in which $bin_2$ doesn't have a ball i.e all the balls are distributed into bins : $bin_1$ and $bin_2$. This gives two options for each ball therefore $2^4 = 16$ ways.

Therefore total number of ways of distributing 4 distinct balls into 3 distinct bins such that $bin_2$ always gets a ball is $3^4-2^4 = 65$.

Is this approach and this answer correct ??

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think your method is spot on. Instead of bins I like to call them colours, so that we colour 4 balls, numbered 1 to 4 using three colours $c_1,c_2,c_3$. That is the same thing, really. The total number of colourings is $3^4$ as we are making $4$ independent choices for colours of the balls, with three options per choice, so $3 ^4 = 81$ colourings.

The ones where $c_2$ is not used is $2^4$ for the same reasons (just two options, $4$ times), so $16$ "wrong" colourings, leaving $81 - 16 = 65$ correct colourings.